# Creating full select dropdown from SQL using Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, mysql, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to fill a select dropdown using SQL with Fat Free Framework

The SQL is basic and standard:

```
 SELECT * FROM `lines_list`;
```

will return id, type

all I need it do do is fill a select box:

```
 <option value=$row['id']>$row['type']</option>
```

f3 is confusing the life out of me now but I need to get my head around it.

Can anyone shed some light?

EDIT:

I need to know the right code within f3, here is what I have at the moment:

```
    $rows=$this->db->exec('SELECT * FROM line_list ORDER BY id DESC');
    foreach($rows as $row)
       echo $row['type'];
```

which will happily echo the list but I don't know how to use this information properly in f3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that hard to solve.

First put the result in the hive. This makes it available everywhere, even in your template (if you are using the Template engine for rendering)

```
$f3 = \Base::instance();
$rows=$this->db->exec('SELECT * FROM line_list ORDER BY id DESC');
$f3->set('line_list',$rows);
```

Now put a repeat block into your template:

```
<select name="foo">
<repeat group="{{@line_list}}" value="{{@row}}">
  <option value="{{@row.id}}">{{@row.type}}</option>
</repeat>
</select>
```

That should it be.

Comment: check the template directives for more examples: http://fatfreeframework.com/quick-reference#TemplateDirectives

Comment: How to set selected value ?

Comment: that would go like `<option value="{{@row.id}}" {{(isset(@POST.foo) && @POST.foo == @row.id) ? 'selected=selected' : '' }}>{{@row.type}}</option>`

Comment: I thought there is some special way :D . I'm using 
<check if="{{@POST.foo == @row.id}}">selected</check>

Comment: if you want more magic here, have a look at some custom tag handlers that'll care about data binding automatically ;) https://github.com/ikkez/F3-Sugar/tree/master-v3/FooForms